# PHP Try Catch no sigue el flujo del programa

Tags: php

El Try Catch de mi codigo no sigue el flujo del programa despues del error.
se queda en el segundo Echo de los 3 del final, nunca llega a ejecutar el ultimo Echo.

El resultado es este:

30
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int in C:\xampp\htdocs\semana3\ejercicio3.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\semana3\ejercicio3.php(16): suma('ff', 4) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\semana3\ejercicio3.php on line 7

```
function suma($num1 , $num2)
    {
        try
        {
            return $num1 + $num2; 
            
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    
    echo suma(10,20); 
    echo suma("ff",4);
    echo suma(30,40);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se pueden manejar advertencias ni errores del interprete con `try/catch` ya que no son excepciones.

### Opción 1:

Si tu intención es poder manejar esto usando `try/catch` entonces podrías validar el tipo de dato de cada parámetro y lanzar una excepción.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

function suma($num1, $num2)
{
    try {
        if (!is_numeric($num1)) {
            throw new Exception('El primer parámetro no es numérico. (' . $num1 . ')');
        }
        if (!is_numeric($num2)) {
            throw new Exception('El segundo parámetro no es numérico. (' . $num2 . ')');
        }

        //
        return $num1 + $num2;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}

echo suma(10, 20);
echo suma("ff", 4);
echo suma(30, 40);
```

---

### Opción 2:

Otra opción es utilizar [`set_error_handler`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler.php) para convertir los mensajes de error en excepciones.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
function exception_error_handler($severidad, $mensaje, $fichero, $línea) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $severidad)) {
        // Este código de error no está incluido en error_reporting
        return;
    }
    throw new ErrorException($mensaje, 0, $severidad, $fichero, $línea);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

function suma($num1, $num2)
{
    try {
        return $num1 + $num2;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}

echo suma(10, 20);
echo suma("ff", 4);
echo suma(30, 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

deberías tener una variable Resultado y el error dice que estas sumando un tipo de data Carácter y otro Entero por eso el retorno da error

`$num1 = 10;'
' $num2 = 30;'
'$Resultado = $num1 + $num2'